# 403 - Forbidden error for a Request Mapping in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, controller, http-status-code-403, request-mapping

I am writing a simple Spring MVC Controller with a few basic Request Mappings as follows.

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping("/showReg")
    public String showRegistration() {
        return "login/registerUser";        
    }

    @RequestMapping("/showReg1")
    public String showRegistration1() {
        return "login/registerUser";        
    }
}
```

Accessing localhost:8080/showReg gives the desired result.

But, localhost:8080/showReg1 is giving me 403 - Forbidden.

I am sure I am missing something very simple. What exactly is it? Kindly help me resolve the issue.

Comment: both are returning same result ..?

Comment: update your question with complete code

Comment: I think so you don't have resource mapping with "showReg1". Kindly verify.

Comment: @RaheelaAslam The Controller in the code clearly shows the mapping. And if there is no mapping, it would throw 404 Not Found, not 403 - Forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all the urls are secured in spring security.

Check your security config file. you might have opened the url from the security something like below.

For xml configuration :

```
<http pattern="/showReg" security="none"/>
```

OR java configuration :

```
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
     web.ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/showReg/**");
}
```